# Best practice for application-wide initialization shared by several Autofac components? (Aspose license in this case.)

Tags: c#, autofac, aspose

We're using Autofac and some of our components use Aspose libraries, which require a license. The license is loaded like this:

```csharp
   public class MyAutofacModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            // [Register stuff]
            LoadAsposeLicense();
        }

        private void LoadAsposeLicense()
        {
            // Load the Aspose license.
            string licenseFile = Path.Combine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "..", "Aspose.Total.lic");
            Aspose.Slides.License license = new Aspose.Slides.License();
            license.SetLicense(licenseFile);
        }
    }
```

I thought that was a good idea until I wanted to reuse the DLL from some code that doesn't need the Aspose functionality. We have a license for all Aspose products, but right now, we only use the PowerPoint stuff. However, in the future that may change and we may have other components that will need the Word functionality. The license would be the same, but I guess it would have to be initialized separately.

I am wondering whether it could make sense to introduce a simple license component like this, which would be registered as a singleton (or I could be even lazier and put the code into a static constructor):

```csharp
    class AsposeSlidesLicense
    {
        public AsposeSlidesLicense()
        {
            string licenseFile = Path.Combine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "..", "Aspose.Total.lic");
            Aspose.Slides.License license = new Aspose.Slides.License();
            license.SetLicense(licenseFile);
        }
    }
```

I could then use it like this:

```csharp
    class MyComponentThatUsesAspose : ISlidesCreatorService
    {
        public MyComponentThatUsesAspose(AsposeSlidesLicense license)
        {
            // Dummy constructor to make sure the license is loaded
        }

        public void CreateSlide()
        {
            // Use Aspose library
        }
    }
```

But since the `license` dependency (parameter) has no other function than to trigger the license loading, I'm a bit worried, it may be optimized away either by the compiler, Resharper or another developer.

So my question is:

**What's the best place to put initialization code like this, that may be required by several components to have run *once*?**
And only when those services are needed (components are instantiated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run code when a component is requested you can use the `OnActivating` [*autofac* lifetime event](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/events.html)

You can listen to such event at registration and each time a component is requested, this event will be fired.

```
builder.RegisterType<LicenseVerifier>()
       .As<ILicenseVerifier>()
       .SingleInstance()


builder.RegisterType<YourComponent>()
       .OnActivating(e => e.Context.Resolve<ILicenseVerifier>().EnsureLicense())
```

in your `EnsureLicense` you can do whatever you want to ensure the license is applied.

If you have lots of component it may be a good idea to wrap the `OnActivating` call to a custom method extension and write something like :

```
builder.RegisterType<YourComponent>()
       .WithLicense()
```

another option would be to add an attribute to `YourComponent`

```
[RequireLicense]
public class YourComponent {}
```

and create an autofac Module that will add the `OnActivating` part to all components having the attribute.

---

If you want to run code when the application starts Autofac has 2 mechanisms.

- You can implements `IStartable` it's an *Autofac* interface that run when the container is built.

  ```
    public class StartupMessageWriter : IStartable
    {
      public void Start()
      {
        Console.WriteLine("App is starting up!");
      }
    }
  ```

  and register it like this :

  ```
    builder
     .RegisterType<StartupMessageWriter>()
     .As<IStartable>()
     .SingleInstance();
  ```
- You can register a component with `AutoActivate`. In such case the component will be build when the container is built

  ```
    builder
      .RegisterType<TypeRequiringWarmStart>()
      .AsSelf()
      .AutoActivate();
  ```
- you can also create your own interface and resolve these after container initialization.

you can find more information about autofac in the [running code at container build](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/startup.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that might be useful for other scenarios. Sorry, my question obviously wasn't worded properly: My code is run at startup now and it works just fine. But I only want the code to run once one or more specific components are instantiated. It's a singleton dependency shared by several components, in that sense. Right now, my module always requires that license to exist, even when the calling code doesn't need the specific services.

Comment: Thank you! The attribute solution looks very nice. What is your opinion on using a "dummy dependency" like I suggested (a dependency that is only included in the constructor to make sure the license will be loaded)?

Comment: I avoid having business logic in constructor (https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). You can move your logic to a  `EnsureLicense` method and call this method in some methods of your components. But I prefer a solution using attribute which is more concise and your component doesn't have to know about licensing. You can also extends this using castle dynamic proxy to generate proxy ([AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)) to add the license stuff for some methods.

Comment: There wouldn't be any logic in the constructor - quite the contrary: There would be a seemingly unused constructor parameter for the license service. The "logic" would be handled by Autofac, namely creating only a singleton instance of that service. So the implementing component would simply load the license and Autofac would make sure it won't be loaded twice. That way I would achieve the same thing. But it would look as if the ILicenseService dependency could be removed.

Comment: There will be logic in the constructor of LicenseService. Even if it's simple logic (loading a file ?) there is still logic and it may be better to put that logic in a method instead of a constructor